# jQuery UI draggable/droppable - revert certain elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have container with draggable elements. Now when there is a collision element returns to original position. Is it possible to enable collisions on elements with different class?

Example:

```
<div class="level1 button">button text</div>
<div class="level1 label">label text</div>
<div class="level2 image"></div>
<div class="level2 camera"></div>
```

In above example when is collision .button with .label element should return to original position. (same class level1). Same for .image and .camera. But when is collision button with image is ok.

My current code:

```
elem.draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    containment: "parent",
    start: function () {
        $(".editor > div").popover('hide');
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).draggable('option', 'revert', 'invalid');
        if (!savePos) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.$eval(attr.xpos + '=' + ui.position.left);
                scope.$eval(attr.ypos + '=' + ui.position.top);
            });
        }
        savePos = false;
    }
}).droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
        savePos = true;
    }
});
```

---

OK I did it. Added to elements custom atrribute ui-level and check in doppable:

```
.droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){
    if($(ui.draggable.context).attr("ui-level") == $(event.target).attr("ui-level"))
       ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',false);
    else
       ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);

    savePos = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: if the problem is fixed. please add the fix as an answer and accept it or delete the question. otherwise it'll remain unanswered forever.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a map with the countries. Every country is a *droppable* element. And you have the country flags (*draggables*) that need to be dropped on the countries. Only matching flag can be dropped on the country. Each country and flag has the `data-country_id` attribute set.

When you drop the element, you want to compare them. All the magic hides in `accept` parameter.

```
$("#map .country").droppable({
    hoverClass: "hovered",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    accept: function (e) { if (e.data("country_id") == $(this).data("country_id")) return true; },
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        //insert the code that runs after element has been succesfully dropped
    }
})
```